# If statement in the Json object by using get String not working

Tags: java, android, c, json

I am trying to compare between the two strings by the url response when it executes its directly going to the else statement its not executing the if statement
 **if(response.getString("status").equals("success")**
This is my JSON
**{"status":"success","amount":"5.00","price_func":"%"}
discode=Sfkt1x8H0K**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.checkout);
        checkbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.checktoolbar);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            checkbar.setTitle("Check Out");
        }
    setSupportActionBar(checkbar);
    assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    Button apply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.apply);
    apply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            EditText entercode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entercode);
            String code = entercode.getText().toString();
            String url = "http://www.yell4food.com/json/json_vocher.php?discount=" + code;
            Log.d("code", url);
            JsonObjectRequest promo = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONParser checks = new JSONParser();
                        if(response.getString("status").equals("success")){
                            Toast.makeText(Check.this, "Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            checks.setAmount(response.getString("amount"));
                            checks.setPricefunc(response.getString("price_func"));
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(Check.this, "Nooo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(promo);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you checked that your status is actually `success` not any other value? (Note: case matters)

Comment: Are you sure that the anonymous class' code is actually being executed? try adding some debug print statements.

Comment: yes i had just copied the same name as it is

Comment: i had tried it by adding the anonymous debug also the log statements

Comment: Can you say a sample `code` which produces `success` result? @AyubBaba

Comment: Discount code you used to append in the url.

Comment: this is the json i am using {"status":"success","amount":"5.00","price_func":"%"}

Comment: @AyubBaba Listen, i didn't ask the json response. I asked the success discount code you pass here `            String url = "http://www.yell4food.com/json/json_vocher.php?discount=" + code;`

Comment: Sfkt1x8H0K this is the discount code i am using sorry i got confused

Comment: @AyubBaba Are you sure is this correct code? I didn't get any response. It shows empty status.

Comment: http://www.yell4food.com/json/json_vocher_updated.php?discount=Sfkt1x8H0K yes i am using that one only

Comment: I had tried this method too Where                                                        String stat=response.getString("status");if(stat.equals("success"))

Comment: @AyubBaba Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, the problem is you are using different URL and got confused.

In the question, look your url

```
String url = "http://www.yell4food.com/json/json_vocher.php?discount=" + code;
```

In the comment section, look your url

```
http://www.yell4food.com/json/json_vocher_updated.php?discount=Sfkt1x8H0K
```

`json_vocher.php` vs `json_vocher_updated.php`

Comment: i am passing the text from the edittext to check if the discount of the promo code is success then they will get the discount if not the code will return the invalid code and in the comment url thats the success discount code

Comment: Yes, so which URL you are actually using. Understand, for the code `Sfkt1x8H0K`, the response for status is empty if i use the first URL and i get the response status success in the second URL. You have to think what i am trying to say.

Comment: If the discount of the promo code is success, then it will run in the if loop. Until it find the success response, it will run only in else part.

Comment: i am using the url which i had sent to u same as it is

Comment: then replace the url part as `String url = "http://www.yell4food.com/json/json_vocher_updated.php?discount=" + code;`

Comment: Build and run, let me know the status. Make sure you don't include any space at the end while you inputing data in app.

Comment: working like charm..what wrong did i done ?not able to understand

Comment: Now read my answer. Different url (php page). Accept and upvote if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: thanks a lot Different url (php page). Accept and upvote??whats this i havnt understood it?

Comment: I mean, accept my answer as helpful and upvote it. More about http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Try below code if you sure your response status is success

```
if(response.getString("status").trim().equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
```

Triming of String will remove whitespaces from the response String and equalsIgnoreCase will compare both Strings case-insensitively

Otherwise, the problem is something else

Comment: your status value might not be success

Comment: if its still hitting else condition

Comment: {"status":"success","amount":"5.00","price_func":"%"} this is the json i am using.